# How the intent filters of all applications are managed in android system?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I was asked a question in an interview that all android applications has declared intent filters in their manifest file so at the time of intent resolution how the android system resolve the intent by searching all the application's manifest file or is there any implementation in android system that will record all the intent filters and from there it will search.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved with the help of intent filter defined in the menifest file. you will get good idea from this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

When Android OS receive a implicit Intent request it search all the package which are installed in the application. If no application is installed which can handle you implecit intent then you get ActivityNotFound Exception.

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
  final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
  List<ResolveInfo> list =
    mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
      PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
  return list.size() > 0;
}
```

You can take a look in this link.

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=lp0QAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA393&lpg=PA393&dq=how+android+os+resolve+implicit+intent&source=bl&ots=SKwCeFioNF&sig=7ao1EsrNReyeSLdvEtjDLzB_2Os&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F-j2U7bTAs--uAStxoL4CA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=how%20android%20os%20resolve%20implicit%20intent&f=false

Comment: yes but my question is not that. We declare intent filter in manifest file after installing our application where it is stored? if it is stored at the same place then, android system must searching all application's manifest file to resolve it. so to resolve all the intent filter android system have to search all the applications manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I bet Android registers all the intent filters declared on your manifest file at installation time, i dont know how exactly though. Thats how you can access the application info at run-time from the `PackageManager` object. Specifically, you can check out all the information regarding activities and you can even query them based on intents:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> inf = manager.queryIntentActivities (intent, flag);
```